# Multiple Sum Aggregations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running into an issue when I have multiple columns with sum aggregation causing multiple rows to be formed instead of just one.  Each code when run separately, only results in one row, but once I have more than one aggregation, it multiplies; all the same values.

Here is a rough example of what my code looks like right now:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT (SUM(Units * Price) 
     FROM SalesDetail 
     WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, JulianDate) - ((1000*(CONVERT(int, JulianDate) / 1000))) - 1, DATEADD(year, CONVERT(int, JulianDate / 1000), '1 Jan 1900')), 111) LIKE '2018%' G AS ‘2018 Sales’,
    (SELECT (SUM(Units * Price) 
     FROM SalesDetail 
     WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int,JulianDate)-((1000*(CONVERT(int,JulianDate)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(year,CONVERT(int,JulianDate/1000),'1 Jan 1900')),111)  like '2019%' as ‘2019 Sales’
FROM 
     SalesDetail
```

I realize I can use Top 1 to reduce these, but I need to do further analysis with this query that would be broken with that coding

I tried adding just top 1 to each column individually, and am still running into multiples.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  And a clear explanation of the logic the code should be implementing.  Also explain the date calculations which look really arcane and needlessly complicated.

Comment: The date conversions are for moving from Julian to Gregorian and then pulling out the year to filter into just the year sales.  Desired output is just 2018 sales in one column, 2019 sales in another.  Aggregated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be using conditional aggregation and only hitting your `SalesDetail` table once. I'm unable to test this - however I believe this is what you need

```
select 
    sum (case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int,JulianDate)-((1000*(CONVERT(int,JulianDate)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(year,CONVERT(int,JulianDate/1000),'1 Jan 1900')),111) LIKE '2018%' then Units*Price end) as [2018 Sales],
    Sum (case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int,JulianDate)-((1000*(CONVERT(int,JulianDate)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(year,CONVERT(int,JulianDate/1000),'1 Jan 1900')),111) LIKE '2019%' then Units*Price end) as [2019 Sales]
from SalesDetail
```

Comment: There has to be a way to make this SQL more readable.  Scaler functions

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to just get rid of the `FROM SalesDetail` part, at the bottom in the main query body.

Right now, it is selecting every row in `SalesDetail` (main `FROM` clause, with no `WHERE` clause). For each of those rows, the columns selected consist of your two subqueries that produce the aggregates. So, it shows the total many times - one time for each row that exists in `SalesDetail`.

Removing the main `FROM` clause will cause the subqueries to run just once, and produce just one row.

Comment: I need one  table with all of the data, not each value separated out.